# (How) Does Damage Affect Module Performance?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I've been a bit obsessive with my Auto Field-Maintenance Unit (AFMU) usage ever since I got one. Every time a module takes even 1% damage, I stop to repair it. So far, it hasn't been a big deal since I've hardly ever run through a quarter of the AFMU's supplies before returning to a station.

Still, I'm left wondering how much of these repairs are actually worthwhile? Since, for the most part, my modules have never dropped below 90% health, I don't really know which ones really need to be kept in top shape for best performance or which ones I can leave for the starport mechanics to deal with.

Does damage affect the performance of modules, or is it just a "health meter" that shows you how close the module is to becoming inoperable?

If there is an incremental effect, how is this applied? Is it substantially different for each module? Are there certain modules that are glaring exceptions?

Comment: As far as i know, modules have three states: "working", manually deactivated", "broken". I never noticed a difference between a brand new module and a partially damaged one. So, i'd also appreciate confirmation, if possible :3

Comment: I use the 5 priorities of module setup (right panel) and I swear, taking power-plant damage degrades its performance- in some instances, keeping only thrusters and fsd in priority 1 has enabled me to escape when all my other systems have been without power... this was quite a few patches ago so it might have changed since.
It might also be connected to recent damage because after a short while systems (like life support which I set at P3) came online again.

Answer (score 1):

**Damage does not affect the performance of modules.**

It only determines the frequency of malfunctions. (e.g. an FSD at 75% will start to malfunction - the more damage it takes the more it will malfunction)

The only module that has an incremental effect AFAIK is the canopy, that only shows visual cracks.

Keep in mind that a malfunction does affect the module performance so you might want to repair a module as soon as it drops under 80% to prevent performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find clear information on this, but I believe that at low health (<25%?) modules can randomly malfunction - they may stop working properly. For example, I've had my power distributor malfunction and randomly reassign my power. Once they hit 0% they just stop working entirely obviously.

When a module does malfunction sometimes you can just wait it out, but manually rebooting it via the `Modules` panel has always fixed it for me.

Unless you're exploring far from populated space or doing lots of combat and don't want to have to retreat to repair, you won't really need an AFMU much.

Comment: Yeah, the exploring bit. That's me. Currently ~12.5 kLy from the bubble, inbound - and I dared to leave the AFMUs at home this time. Hull 57% (which I know AFMUs wouldn't help anyway), Cockpit Canopy 80%. Need to start paying better attention - quit faceplanting into stars, and check gravimetrics before landing!

Comment: @Iszi If you have horizons available, I highly recommend getting the heavy duty armor mod from Selene Jean if possible - it boosts the hull strength and resistances, and increases the mass of the armor by a %, but the lightweight alloy armor has zero weight so it's literally free hull. AFMUs can take care of canopy, so definitely pick up one of those, two if you're planning on going into really deep space (so that you can use one to repair the other)

Comment: Currently on my way back from Colonia. I did come out with 2 AFMUs, but I dumped those to make room for rares on the way back. Figured I didn't take too many hits coming out, so it wouldn't be a big deal. I *should* be able to make it, so long as I behave myself from here on out. I'll have to keep hull mods in mind though - didn't think they'd be possible on lightweight, since it would seem to throw off the game balance a bit by allowing you to beef up zero-weight armor. For the immediate future though, all my Engineering is going to FSD.